# "I hope you all/both are doing well" vs "I hope you are all/both doing well"?

Tags: pronouns, word-order, dialects, transatlantic-differences, quantifiers

Do both convey the same message, or not?

1. I hope **you all are** doing well.
2. I hope **you are all** doing well.

It occurs to me that the same thing happens with *both* when I'm only addressing two people rather than more than two:

3. I hope **you both are** doing well.
4. I hope **you are both** doing well.

I'm sure that the first of each pair addresses more than one person, but I'm not sure if it is as “grammatically correct” as the second from each pair where the quantifier follows the verb instead of the pronoun.

I just wanted to check up on  my friends but I'm not sure which one I should use; I'm a non-native speaker.

Comment: Both convey the same message, but the second is what most native speakers would say. (I know _you all_ is used in some parts of the USA when addressing several people.)

Comment: You are on the wrong site! Please read the Tour to find the scope of this site. There is a sister site English Language Learners that may be appropriate.

Comment: why would you think they're not grammatically correct? anyway you they are: both sets... perhaps '... you each are doing well' would be a little "iffy" for some folks, as compared to '... you are each doing well'

Answer (score 2):

Y'all shouldn't be askin' these questions. Chucks, almighty! You folks figgerin'on gettin' here with us Texans?
"I hope you ARE ALL doing well."
"You all" is American dialect (especially Texan, as far as I know).

Comment: Cripes on a crock, what's wit’ all th’ cussin’ an’ on a Sondee no less! I bet Misser Colina is just one person, not a whole gaggle of ’em! Cuz doncha know tha’ mos’ly **Only In Texas™** is *yall* an ack-chew-well sing’lar, what with *allyall* bein’ those folkseses’ plural.

Comment: Ah'm so sorry Sir, if Ah despleesed yah. Ah wuz jussa tellin' them Limey folks how dey should conduct demselves. I deeply un honestly apologize to you folks down dere in Texas. Ah'm jussa shtupid sonofagun from Britain, England. Guess what? I love Texas. I was there in 2003-4, with my fiancee from Pennsylvania who resided there. I love your state, especially now, with Pete Buttigieg  
and Julián Castro. I was at the Alamo. (Too late to save Davy or the Colonel, though.)